# $\lim_{x\to 1^-}\sqrt{1-x}\ \left(1+x+x^4+x^9+x^{16}+x^{25}+\cdots\right)=\sqrt{\pi}/2$ is true?

Tags: limits

When I was considering limits of various functions, I had the following conjecture.

$$\lim_{x \to 1^-}\sqrt{1-x}\ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^{\left(k^2\right)}=\lim_{x\to 1^-}\sqrt{1-x}\ \left(1+x+x^4+x^9+x^{16}+x^{25}+\cdots\right)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$$

This seems true, but I can't prove that. If this is true, how can we prove that? If this is not true, what is the answer?

Comment: In general, $~\displaystyle\lim_{x\to1^-}~\sqrt[a]{1-x}\cdot\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n^a}~=~\int_0^\infty e^{-t^a}~dt~=~\Gamma\bigg(1+\dfrac1a\bigg)$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let
$$ f(x)=1+\sum_{n\geq 1} x^{n^2}=\frac{1+\vartheta_3(x)}{2}. $$
Then for any $x$ such that $|x|<1$ we have:
$$ f(x)^2 = 1+\sum_{n\geq 1} r_2(n)\,x^n $$
where:
$$ r_2(n) = \#\left\{(a,b)\in\mathbb{N}_0^2: a^2+b^2=n\right\}, $$
and since the last number theoretic function is well-known, and leads to the following [Lambert series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertSeries.html) identity about the [Jacobi theta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html) $\vartheta_3$:
$$ \vartheta_3(x)^2 = 1+4\left(\frac{x}{1-x}-\frac{x^3}{1-x^3}+\frac{x^5}{1-x^5}-\frac{x^7}{1-x^7}+\ldots\right)\tag{1}$$
your limit is just the positive square root of:
$$ \frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}+\ldots=\arctan(1)=\frac{\pi}{4}\tag{2}$$
proving your conjecture.

Comment: sorry, I want to know that where is the function$\sqrt{1-x}$ in your answer?

Comment: @Easy: Take the square of the limit. Then you have to evaluate the limit for $x\to 1^{-}$ of $(1)$ multiplied by $(1-x)$. That leads to $(2)$.

Comment: ok, thanks Mr.Jack

Comment: This can easily be generalized to the $\Gamma$ function: see my comment on the main post.

Answer (score 6):

We have the following theorem from G. Polya's book:

> **Theorem**: Let for the monotonic function $f$ , $\int_{0}^\infty f(x)dx$ exists and we have $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$ and $f(x)>0$ then
>   we have
>
> $$\lim_{h\to0^+}h\sum_{v=0}^\infty f(vh)=\int_{0}^\infty f(x)dx.$$
>
> By using this theorem we can show,
>
> $$\lim_{t\to
>  1^{-}}\sqrt[\alpha]{1-t}(1+t^{1^\alpha}+t^{2^\alpha}+t^{3^\alpha}+\cdots+t^{n^\alpha}+\cdots)=\frac{1}{\alpha}\Gamma(\frac{1}{\alpha}).$$

We need to take in previous theorem $t=e^{-h^{\alpha}}$ and $f(x)=e^{-x^\alpha}$ and since $\Gamma(\alpha)=\int_0^\infty e^{-x}x^{\alpha-1}dx$ and $\ln(1-t)\cong 1-t$.

See this book: G. Polya and Gabor Szegö, *[Problems and theorems in analysis](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540636403)* , vol. I, Springer.

Answer (score 5):

From the first relation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function#Relation_to_the_Riemann_zeta_function) and $\tau = \textrm{i}\alpha$ for $\alpha >0$ it follows that $$ \sqrt{\alpha} \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} e^{-\pi\alpha k^2}= \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}e^{-\pi\alpha^{-1}k^2}.$$ For $\alpha\downarrow 0$ this shows that $$ \lim_{\alpha\downarrow 0}\sqrt{\alpha} \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} e^{-\pi\alpha k^2}= 1.$$ Now $$ \lim_{\alpha\downarrow 0}\sqrt{\alpha} \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} e^{-\pi\alpha k^2} = \lim_{\alpha\downarrow 0}  \sqrt{\frac{1-e^{-\pi\alpha}}{\pi}}\left(1+2\sum_{k\geq 1}e^{-\pi \alpha k^2}\right) $$ and with $x=e^{-\pi\alpha}$ your result follows.