# Evaluate $ \lim_{h \to 0} h\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-n^2h^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits, riemann-sum

Evaluate

$$ \lim_{h \to 0} h\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-n^2h^2}$$

I think it is somehow related to Riemann Sums, but I'm not sure.
Please help.

Comment: See related https://math.stackexchange.com/q/179249/72031

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think a good way is to use [integral test for convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence).

This shows that for all $h > 0$, you have :
$$|\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-n^2 h^2} - \int_0^\infty e^{-x^2 h^2} dx| \leq 1$$.
Using this you can see that 
$$\lim_{h \to 0} h \sum_{n=0}^\infty  e^{-n^2 h^2} = \lim_{h \to 0} h  \int_0^\infty e^{-x^2 h^2} dx$$.
This last integral is a Gaussian integral, and can be evaluated for any $h > 0$:
$$ \int_0^\infty e^{-x^2 h^2} dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \frac{1}{h}$$

So finally $$\lim_{h \to 0} h \sum_{n=0}^\infty  e^{-n^2 h^2} = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$$

Answer (score 4):

If a function $f$ is Riemann-integrable on $[0,\infty)$, then its integral $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx$ is equal to
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\,h\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(nh)$$
Now you just have to set $f$ appropriately. See [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral) if you can't do the resulting integration.

**Edited to add:** As commenters have pointed out, I have over-simplified here. What I should have said was this:

Let $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow \Bbb R$ be a function of [bounded variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation), and suppose that it is Riemann-integrable over $[0,M]$ for all $M\ge 0$, and that $\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^M f(x)\;dx$ exists. Then this limit, which we denote by $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx$, is equal to
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\,h\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(nh)$$

Comment: What theorem did you use? Can you give a short proof or a reference?

Comment: I used the definition of the Riemann integral.

Comment: I only know these definitions and properties listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral).

Comment: This requires some additional hypotheses like $f$ being monotone and is not really a definition but rather a theorem with not so easy proof.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: I am simply choosing my partition to be $0<h<2h<\ldots N$ for some provosional limit $N$, letting $h$ tend to zero to get the Riemann integral over $[0,N]$, and then letting $N$ tend t0 infinity to get the integral over $[0,\infty)$. Very straightforward stuff. (BTW, $f$ doesn't have to be monotone. It just has to be Riemann-integrable, as I said.)

Comment: Well an improper integral is limit of a proper integral which is a limit of a sum. This implies that an imtegral is an iterated limit of two variables and in general one can't replace that with a single variable limit unless some extra conditions are met. For the case of improper integrals with bounded domain and unbounded functions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1745876/72031) is a proof which uses monotone nature. A similar analysis is needed here also.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I have posted a question based on that [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2970721/a-property-of-a-riemann-integrable-function).

Comment: @TonyK I have posted a question based on that [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2970721/a-property-of-a-riemann-integrable-function). Can you elaborate your comment as an answer?

Comment: There's a simple counterexample here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2970721/a-property-of-a-riemann-integrable-function/2970767#2970767

Comment: "Very straightforward stuff.": But totally wrong. Your error is assuming that $\lim_{N\to\infty}\lim_{h\to0}=\lim_{h\to0}\lim_{N\to\infty}$. Limits don't automatically commute like that, in fact many theorems in analysis amount to showing that you _can_ sometimes switch the order of two limits.

Comment: I think you meant to use this [Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2627075/455956), which doesn't hold true for all Riemann Integrable functions necessarily.