# A property of a Riemann Integrable function

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, limits, riemann-sum

It was posted in an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2968963/evaluate-lim-h-to-0-h-sum-n-0-infty-e-n2h2/2968976#2968976) to my previous question that

> If a function $f$ is Riemann-integrable on $[0,\infty)$, then,
>
> $$\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\,h\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(nh)$$

How can we prove this proposition? I only know of the standard definition of Riemann Sums involving lim sup and lim inf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is false.

Strictly speaking it's meaningless, because there's no such thing as "Riemann integrable on $[0,\infty)$"; the Riemann integral is defined for functions that have a *compact* interval for their domain. Presumably here $\int_0^\infty$ is supposed to be an improper Riemann integral, which is to say the reasonable interpretation of the proposition in question is

> If a function $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,A]$ for every $A>0$ and $\int_0^\infty f=\lim_{A\to\infty}\int_0^A  f$ exists then
>
> $$\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\,h\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(nh).$$

*That* is false.

Choose $A_n$ increasing to infinity such that $A_1=0$ and $A_{n+1}-A_n$ decreases to $0$ (for example, $A_n=\log(n)$).  Let $f(t)=(-1)^n$ for $A_n\le t<A_{n+1}$. Then $\int_0^\infty f$ exists, more or less by the proof of the alternating series test for sums, but $\sum_nf(nh)$ does not exist, since the terms do not even tend to $0$.

**Details:** Regarding existence of $\int_0^\infty f$: First, the alternating series test for sums shows that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{A_n}f$$exists. And it's clear that $$\left|\int_0^Af-\int_0^{A_n}f\right|\le A_{n+1}-A_n\quad(A_n\le A\le A_{n+1}).$$Since $A_{n+1}-A_n\to0$ this shows that $\lim_{A\to\infty}\int_0^A$ exists.

Comment: Thanks! I think the OP meant this [Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2627075/455956), which doesn't hold for all Riemann functions in general.

Comment: @Robin No, the OP didn't  mean that. We know because in that other thread he or she _said_ that montonicity was not required.

Comment: Yes, yes. I mean he didn't know of the explicit conditions, but meant to use that result.