# Evaluating: $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n^{2}} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, theta-functions

How do you evaluate:
$\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n^{2}} $
Or more generally
$ \large\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n^{\alpha}}   $
Note that: $|x| <1$

Comment: Since you added the tag, you probably know that the first summation is $\frac{1}{2} (1+\vartheta _3(0,x))$. For the general case, I don't know if there is any closed form.

Comment: There is no closed form for a general $\alpha$, but we do have this [interesting property](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196721).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the Jacobi Theta function
$$
\vartheta_3(z,q) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{2 i n z} q^{n^2}
$$

so yours is
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n^2} = \frac{\vartheta_3(0,x)+1}{2}
$$

Of course for $a=1$ it can also be evaluated using known functions.  But not for other values of $a$.