# Does this limit... exist?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, power-series

I found this interesting function defined by the following infinite series:

$$g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nx^{2^n}$$

And I noticed that it followed the functional equation $g(x)=1-g(x^2)$.  I was interested, particularly, in the following limit:

$$L=\lim_{x\to1^-}g(x)$$

And assuming it exists, the functional equation yields

$$L=1-L\implies L=\frac12$$

Which, at first look, the limit appears to exist.

[image]

However, upon closer inspection, convergence gets a little sketchy...

[image]

Can we determine if the limit converges?

Comment: It didn't converge, see answers of  [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1080746/59379). BTW, the functional equation should be $g(x) = x - g(x^2)$.

Comment: For $|x|<1$, you have
$$
|(-1)^{n} x^{2^{n}}| < |x|^{n},
$$
so the series is majorized by the convergent geometric series $\sum_{n \geq 0} x^{n}$.

For $|x| = 1$, the partial sums of the series form the alternating sequence $-1, 1, -1, 1, \ldots, $ hence fail to converge.

Comment: @avs But $\lim_{x\to1^-}\sum_{n\ge0}(-1)^nx^n=\frac12$, so I don't see how that helps easily.

Comment: @achillehui That's the functional equation I used, and thank you for the link.